# Minecraft using the /execute command for specific people

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a kit pvp map in vanilla Minecraft, but I ran into a problem. I want specific people to get a certain effect. So I got a `/testfor` command:

```
/testfor @a{SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"Fire Wand"}}}]}
```

This command tests if any person has this specified item name in slot 0. It then turns on a comparator which activates the second command once it finds that person:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~2 ~1 ~ {ExplosivePower:10,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

How can I specify this command to the person holding the named item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a command to apply a label to the player based on their data rather than using `/testfor`. For example, `/scoreboard` can assign a label:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HasItem] remove HasItem
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!HasItem] add HasItem {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"Fire Wand"}}}]}
```

And you'd then target players based on their label. The correct tag for fireball damage is `ExplosionPower`:

```
/execute @a[tag=HasItem] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~2 ~1 ~ {ExplosionPower:10,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

---

If using 1.8, you will have to use a score instead. Objective to create:

```
/scoreboard objectives add HasItem dummy
```

Commands to run for labeling:

```
/scoreboard players set @a HasItem 0
/scoreboard players set @a HasItem 1 {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Fire Wand"}}}}
```

And for targeting, you'd use the `score` parameter:

```
/execute @a[score_HasItem_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~2 ~1 ~ {ExplosionPower:10,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

---

You may be interested in the `SelectedItem` compound, which holds a copy of the player's currently-held item. This way you do not need to specifically test each individual hotbar slot:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!HasItem] add HasItem {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Fire Wand"}}}}
```

Comment: I really appreciate selected items compound command you suggested it will save me a lot of trouble! 

Comment: I tested it out now, but it says that the usage is incorrect, I can't have a tag after the /scoreboard players command! Help!!

Comment: @JP2K What version are you using? Scoreboard "tags" was added in 1.9. If you're using 1.8, you have to use a score instead. I'll update the answer to include a score.

Comment: Thank you very much, since I don't know if all of my commands still work in 1.9

Comment: I'll update you ones I found out if the commands still work

Comment: I ran into another problem! I'm now using the 1.9 version and the command doesn't give me any output, can u please specify the command? I don't seem to get it

Comment: @JP2K Which command are you talking about? No output in the "Last Output" typically means that no targets were found.

Comment: @JP2K To answer [your other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257271). You have to run both `scoreboard` commands in a repeat/chain line, and in this order. This will ensure that the tag is set correctly at all times. The `execute` command needs to be powered whenever you think it should be, i.e. when you want a fireball to be spawned on a player holding the item. If that is whenever a player first starts holding the item, you should clarify the question, since it will likely require a slightly different approach.