# Minecraft command execute problem + 1.9 scoreboard tag problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a kit pvp map in vanilla Minecraft, but I ran into a problem. I want specific people to get a certain effect. So I got a `/testfor` command:

```
/testfor @a{SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"Fire Wand"}}}]}
```

This command tests if any person has this specified item name in slot `0`. It then turns on a comparator which activates the second command once it finds that person:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~2 ~1 ~ {ExplosivePower:10,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

How can I specify this command to the person holding the named item?

So [Skylinerw suggested this command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257193/74333) which seems to solve all my problems!

> You have to use a command to apply a label to the player based on
>   their data rather than using `/testfor`. For example, `/scoreboard`
>   can assign a label:
>
> ```
> /scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HasItem] remove HasItem
> /scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!HasItem] add HasItem {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"Fire Wand"}}}]}
> ```
>
> And you'd then target players based on their label. The correct tag
>   for fireball damage is `ExplosionPower`:
>
> ```
> /execute @a[tag=HasItem] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~2 ~1 ~ {ExplosionPower:10,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
> ```

I thought this is really cool! But how does the scoreboard command activate the execute command? Is it with a comparator? Do both command blocks have to be on a clock?

Comment: This is a clarification request to a specific answer to a question and should be a comment on said answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Both commands must be on a clock.